# I'm getting a blank screen with React JS Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've read some other articles about people facing the same issue but still haven't found anything that works for me. What has me confused is that the Login.js code works when I run it directly without navigation. Likewise, if I change the Login.js code and merely render an H1 tag, it works even with navigation.

**AppRouter.js**

```
class AppRouter extends Component {
 render() {
   return (      
      <BrowserRouter>
       <div>
         <Navigation />
           <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
           <Route component={Error}/>
          </Routes>
       </div> 
     </BrowserRouter>
     
   );
 }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
 
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>
       </div>
    );
}
 
export default Navigation;
```

**Login.js**

```
export default function Login(){
  {
      return (
        <>
        <Header/>
    <Flex
      minH={'100vh'}
      align={'center'}
      justify={'center'}
      bg={useColorModeValue('gray.50', 'gray.800')}>
      <Stack spacing={8} mx={'auto'} maxW={'lg'} py={12} px={8}>
        <Stack align={'center'}>
          <Heading fontSize={'4xl'}>Sign in to your account</Heading>
          <Text fontSize={'lg'} color={'gray.600'}>
            Welcome!<Link color={'blue.400'}>features</Link>
          </Text>
        </Stack>
        <Box
          rounded={'lg'}
          bg={useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.700')}
          boxShadow={'lg'}
          p={8}>
          <Stack spacing={4}>
            <FormControl id="email">
              <FormLabel>Email address</FormLabel>
              <Input type="email" />  
            </FormControl>

            <FormControl id="password">
              <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
              <Input type="password" />
            </FormControl>

            <Stack spacing={10}>
              <Stack
                direction={{ base: 'column', sm: 'row' }}
                align={'start'}
                justify={'space-between'}>
                <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                <Link color={'blue.400'}>Forgot password?</Link>
              </Stack>

              <Button
                bg={'blue.400'}
                color={'white'}
                _hover={{
                  bg: 'blue.500',
                }}>
                Sign in
              </Button>

            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        </Box>
      </Stack>
    </Flex>
    </>
      )
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AppRouter/>   
  );
}
```

Comment: White screen? Is there any error in your console that would explain it perchance?

Comment: first of all remove <div> from inside BrowserRouter as it is pointless and then show us your console output it may be of value here ;)

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? You seem to have mixed v5 and v6 `Route` component API/syntax. From the project directory run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back. The `Link` component in `Login` also appears to be missing a `to` prop, if it's the `Link` component from RRD.

Comment: @DrewReese It's 6.3.0

Comment: @miyavmiyav will do, thanks for pointing out. 
[link](https://i.ibb.co/qkKvQPK/console.png)
Here's a link to the error I'm getting on the console. The terminal doesn't show any error.

Comment: @JakubKotrs thanks for responding. My terminal screen is not showing any error. Here's what my console looks like [link](https://i.ibb.co/qkKvQPK/console.png)

Comment: You are apparently rendering a `Router` component within another `Router` component. You only need one router for the entire app, so remove any extraneous nested routers. Also, fix the "error" route so it matches any path and renders the routed component on the `element` prop like the other routes.

Comment: can you also share index.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
class AppRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route path="/Error" element={<div>Error Message</div>} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/Error" />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-leakey-o0ette?file=/src/App.js)